# Клонирование элементов навигации?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите, разобраться почему по клику на кнопку Каталог, мне после ссылок bl_catalogProducts__link сыпяться только значения Первого списка из навигации added_catalog? Как сделать что б после каждой ссылки шёл соответствующий ей подсписок ?

```js
 var buttonRubrics = $(".btn_categories");

  buttonRubrics.one("click", function() {
    if ($(".bl_catalogProducts").is(":not(.js-addedFooterInfoBlock)")) {
      // Клонируем ссылки информации из футора в Блок оббертку, единожды, пока нету класса
      $(".bl_catalogProducts__link").removeAttr("href");
      /// Убираем href со ссылок

      for (var i = 0; i < $(".bl_catalogProducts__item").length; i++) {
        console.log("li =" + i);

        var li = $(".added_catalog__section")
          .eq(i)
          .clone(true);
        $(".bl_catalogProducts__item")
          .eq(i)
          .append(li);
      }
    }

    fullCategories.toggleClass(active);
  });
```

```css
.added_catalog__section {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bl_catalogProducts">
  <button class="btn_categories visible-sm visible-xs" type="button">Каталог</button>
  <ul class="bl_catalogProducts__full">
    <li class="bl_catalogProducts__item"><a class="bl_catalogProducts__link">УДИЛИЩА</a></li>
    <li class="bl_catalogProducts__item"><a class="bl_catalogProducts__link">КАТУШКИ</a></li>
    <li class="bl_catalogProducts__item"><a class="bl_catalogProducts__link">ЛЕСКИ И ШНУРЫ</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<nav class="added_catalog hidden">
  <ul class="added_catalog__section">
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/spinningovye/"> Спиннинговы</a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/fidernye/"> Фидерные</a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/karpovye/"> Карповые</a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/mahovye/">  Маховые                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/bolonskie/">  Болонские                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/matchevye-418/">   Матчевые                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/bortovye/">  Бортовые                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/serfovye/">  Серфовые                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/nahlystovye-423/">   Нахлыстовые                </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="added_catalog__section">
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/bezinercionnye-416/">
                    Безинерционные                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/multiplikatornye-152/">
                    Мультипликаторные                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/nahlystovye-437/">
                    Нахлыстовые                </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="added_catalog__section">
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/shnury/">
                    Шнуры                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/leski/">
                    Лески                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/flyuorokarbon/">
                    Флюорокарбон                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/nahlystovye-shnury/">
                    Нахлыстовые                </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Я не могу понять, вроде как счётчик "i" должен перебирать значения, но почему-то всем выводит только первый список ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это потому, что с каждой итерацией количество секций в DOM становится на 1 больше, благодаря клонированию. Решением будет произвести выборку элементов до цикла, чтобы она осталась неизменна.

```js
var buttonRubrics = $(".btn_categories");

  buttonRubrics.one("click", function() {
    if ($(".bl_catalogProducts").is(":not(.js-addedFooterInfoBlock)")) {
      // Клонируем ссылки информации из футора в Блок оббертку, единожды, пока нету класса
      $(".bl_catalogProducts__link").removeAttr("href");
      /// Убираем href со ссылок
      let sections=$(".added_catalog__section"),
      items=$(".bl_catalogProducts__item")
      for (var i = 0; i < $(".bl_catalogProducts__item").length; i++) {

        var li = sections
          .eq(i)
          .clone(true);
        items
          .eq(i)
          .append(li);
      }
    }

    fullCategories.toggleClass(active);
  });
```

```css
.added_catalog__section {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bl_catalogProducts">
  <button class="btn_categories visible-sm visible-xs" type="button">Каталог</button>
  <ul class="bl_catalogProducts__full">
    <li class="bl_catalogProducts__item"><a class="bl_catalogProducts__link">УДИЛИЩА</a></li>
    <li class="bl_catalogProducts__item"><a class="bl_catalogProducts__link">КАТУШКИ</a></li>
    <li class="bl_catalogProducts__item"><a class="bl_catalogProducts__link">ЛЕСКИ И ШНУРЫ</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<nav class="added_catalog hidden">
  <ul class="added_catalog__section">
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/spinningovye/"> Спиннинговы</a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/fidernye/"> Фидерные</a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/karpovye/"> Карповые</a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/mahovye/">  Маховые                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/bolonskie/">  Болонские                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/matchevye-418/">   Матчевые                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/bortovye/">  Бортовые                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/serfovye/">  Серфовые                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/nahlystovye-423/">   Нахлыстовые                </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="added_catalog__section">
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/bezinercionnye-416/">
                    Безинерционные                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/multiplikatornye-152/">
                    Мультипликаторные                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/nahlystovye-437/">
                    Нахлыстовые                </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="added_catalog__section">
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/shnury/">
                    Шнуры                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/leski/">
                    Лески                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/flyuorokarbon/">
                    Флюорокарбон                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="added_catalog__item">
      <a href="/nahlystovye-shnury/">
                    Нахлыстовые                </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Спасибо, за решение, хотя понимания почему увеличивается, количество секций в DOM дереве из-за клонирования, не пришло(

Comment: @BlackStar1991 ну вот вы делаете выборку элементов (секций в вашем случае) с классом `added_catalog__section` и получаете 3 разные секции для трёх разных пунктов меню. Далее первую секцию вы клонируете и добавляете к первому пункту меню, из за чего на странице становится уже 4 элемента с классом `added_catalog__section`, тоесть 4 секции, причём новая выше старых. Затем вы снова делаете выборку секций, берёте вторую, но она оказывается той же самой, что и в прошлой итерации, так как перед ней уже появилась ещё одна. И так до конца цикла. Понимаете?

Comment: Всё, теперь дошло. Спасибо